# '[String]' does not have a member named 'text' Swift

Tags: string, swift, runtime-error

I been trying to resolved this issue for awhile and haven't found any solution yet.  `'[String]' does not have a member named 'text'` at `let c:Int? = conversion.text.toInt()`.  I know it has to do with the string being a floating point.  What would be the fix?

```
 @IBOutlet var pickerView1: UIPickerView!

        @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var enterUnits: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var answerConversion: UITextField!
        var measurements = ["m to feet","cm to inches", "mm to inches"]
        var conversion = ["3.12","4.54","5.23"]
```

pickerview

```
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
            if pickerView.tag == 0 {

                let a:Int? = enterUnits.text.toInt()
                let c:Int? = conversion.text.toInt()

                let answer = (a!) * (c!)
                textField1.text = measurements[row]
                answerConversion.text = conversion[row]
                answerConversion.text = "\(answer)"

                }
```

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the array of Double instead of String

```
 let conversion = [3.12,4.54,5.23]
```

And in pickerView you can access like

```
let c = conversion[row]
```

Comment: Tried it already...have error.  ' '[String]' does not have a member named 'toInt'.'

Comment: You can have the array of Int instead of String

Answer (score 1):

`[String]` doesnt have a property text, which is why you get your error. You need to call your `[String]` with a index before you can cast it to a int.

Example:

`myStringArray[myIndex].toInt()`